# Какой скриптовый язык более гибкий при работе с файлами?

Tags: python, linux, perl

Исправляю свой вопрос, чтобы не плодить дискуссии)
Какой скриптовый язык: Perl или Python лучше преспособлен и оптимизирован для автоматизации работы с файлами. Интересует: организация бекапов, сложная выборка файлов в папке по разным принципам.Например, отсортировать файлы по сложной маске, обрезать\заменить части названий.

Comment: Без конкретики по критериям "лучшести" одного языка перед другим вопрос слишком субъективный. Скорее всего, его скоро закроют)

Comment: Если у вас уже есть куча перлового кода - учите перл. Если питоньего - питон.

Comment: пока есть только bash скрипты) на перлом и питоном сталкивался инимаьлно, но хотелось бы изучить) вот пытаюсь определиться с чего начать)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, так ведь интересны именно субъективные мнения (основанные на личном опыте). / TC, в первой редакции  вопрос был лучше (субъективно). Просто основываясь на количестве "системных" скриптов, однозначным ответом (опять субъективно) был бы python.

Comment: Мне тоже в первой редакции вопрос больше нравился) Ну раз попросили переписать - что уж делать)

Answer (score 2):

Начинайте с Python - он проще и гораздо популярнее на данный момент.

Comment: @Dofri, Вам, кажется, повезло. Ответ появился за 15 минут, а еще немного и могло бы  быть уже 5 голосов за закрытие. Вот такие нравы...

Comment: Да вопрос же на самом деле насущный и в англоязычной среде свободно обсуждается: http://serverfault.com/questions/245086/perl-or-python-better-suited-for-unix-system-automation

Comment: zed, спасибо за ссылочку, с удовольствием почитаю)

Comment: @avp: критерии по выбору языка для изучения могут иметь мало общего с самим языком, например, если есть знакомый, у которого можно спросить вопросы по языку, то  это может быть большой аргумент в пользу одного языка по сравнению с другим

Comment: @jfs, бесспорно, но скорее всего в подобном случае мы бы просто не увидели этого вопроса (по крайней мере в его первоначальной формулировке).